# Trouble meeting specification with format errors

Tags: java

System:

```
.out.println("For test 1,");
    for (int i = 0; i < testOne.length; i++)
    {
      System.out.print("Enter score " + (i + 1) + ": ");
      testOne[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("For test 2,");
    for (int i = 0; i < testTwo.length; i++)
    {
      System.out.print("Enter score " + (i + 1) + ": ");
      testTwo[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < average.length; i++)
    {
      average[i] = ((testOne[i] + testTwo[i]) / 2.0D);
      if (Double.doubleToLongBits(average[i]) > Double.doubleToLongBits(90.0D)) {
        grade[i] = 'A';
      } else if (Double.doubleToLongBits(average[i]) > Double.doubleToLongBits(80.0D)) {
        grade[i] = 'B';
      } else if (Double.doubleToLongBits(average[i]) > Double.doubleToLongBits(70.0D)) {
        grade[i] = 'C';
      } else {
        grade[i] = 'F';
      }
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Test 1\tTest 2\tAverage\tGrade");
    System.out.println("------\t------\t-------\t-----");
    for (int i = 0; i < testOne.length; i++) {
      System.out.println(testFormat.format(testOne[i]) + "\t" + testFormat.format(testTwo[i]) + "\t" + averageFormat.format(average[i]) + "\t" + grade[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
The output looks like this:
Test 1  Test 2  Average Grade
------  ------  ------- -----
089 098 093.5   A
097 085 091.0   A
094 096 095.0   A
078 073 075.5   C

 What I need:
 Test 1 Test 2  Average Grade
 ------ ------  ------- -----
 089    098     093.5   A
 097    085     091.0   A
 094    096     095.0   A
 078    073     075.5   C
```

What I was wondering is if someone could help me out with the formatting issues that are preventing me from finishing the program? I need the numbers to fall into the correct column and category because that's what the specification ask for. any help with the simple formatting issues would be great and deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could work with padding:

```
String columnName = "Test 1";
int columnLength = column.length;
System.out.println(String.format("%1$-" + columnLength + "s", value));
```

This gives you a right padding for the size of the column headline. If those values are the type you are expecting this should work fine. If your row values get bigger you have to take care if the width is higher than the headline width. In that case you might also want to increase the space between your headlines.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need `testFormat.format()` and `averageFormat.format()`?

After removing them:

```
for (int i = 0; i < testOne.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(testOne[i] + "\t" + testTwo[i] + "\t" + average[i] + "\t" + grade[i]);
}
```

This is the output:

```
Test 1  Test 2  Average Grade
------  ------  ------- -----
90      56      73.0    C
95      98      96.5    A
90      98      94.0    A
97      99      98.0    A
```